# Cannot acces variables from aspx to cs

Tags: asp.net, computer-science

I have a problem. I have created asp.net web page in c#. I created it using the default master page that visuals studio gives you. There in register.aspx there is a textbox for username like tihs:

```
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                 CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

In cs folder, under the button i put a code that put the registered user into database, but it cannot find the variable of text box. What is the problem here?

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false 

    //string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
    //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
    //{
    //    continueUrl = "~/";
    //}
    //Response.Redirect(continueUrl);

        try
        {
            SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            DataTable objdatatable = new DataTable();
            string validationquery = "select * from Uporabniki where username=`" + UserName.Text + "`";
            SqlDataAdapter objdavalidate = new SqlDataAdapter(validationquery, objcon);
            objdavalidate.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            objdavalidate.Fill(objdatatable);
            if (objdatatable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080906/asp-net-control-not-available-in-codebehind

Comment: Well i dont know, i tried that but i couldnt make it to work, maybe this is some error because of the visual studio aspx template that it generates?